# Change the color of a shape inside a group in VBA for Word

Tags: vba, ms-word

Hello I would like to change the color of a specific shape called "icon1" which is in a group called "box". But there is also other shapes and text boxes in this group (other shapes :"icon2","icon3"/ "text1", "text2") which I don't want to change the color.
I tried to change the color of the "icon1" but VBA told that the item with this name could not be found.

```
Sub changeshapecolor()
ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("icon1")).Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 200, 128)
End Sub
```

Because I thought VBA could not find "icons1" because the shape is in a group, I have also tried with this code but it doesn't work neither.

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes.Range(Array("box")).GroupItems("icon1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 200, 128)
```

I don't know how to fix my problem, could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
ActiveDocument.Shapes("box").GroupItems("icon1").Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 200, 128)
```